How to extract the matching object with 1 operation in Scala?
I have the following piece of code:
foo collectFirst {
  case x if check(expensive(x)) => do_something(expensive(x))
  case x if check2(expensive2(x)) => do_something_else(expensive2(x))
}  

To prevent expensive() being called twice, I can do this:
object expensive_helper {
  def unapply[A, B](x: A): Option[B] =
    ???
}

But, this is pretty verbose. Is there a better way?

foo.map(expensive).filter(check).map(doSomething)

@Dima: Edited the question to be collectFirst to illustrate the problem better

Ok, I can't "edit" the comment, but here goes :D
foo.map(expensive).find(check).map(doSomething)

@Dima - but wouldn't foo.map be eager unless foo is an iterator or lazylist ? Thus if foo.length = 1 million it might call expensive 1 million times even if find occurs in first few items.

yes, sure, it's always better to use an iterator or a view
foo.iterator.map(expensive).find(check).map(doSomething)

@Dima: Ok, updated my question to show that we need the match e.g. when we have a fallback if first match fails

I have this helper in my common utils:
case class matches[A, B](f: A => B)(check: B => Boolean) {
  def unapply(a: A): Option[B] = Option(f(a)).filter(check)
}

Here's how to use it:
val x      = "abcd"
val base64Url = matches((s: String) => Try(Base64.urlDecode(s))
(_.isSuccess)
val base64 = matches((s: String) => Try(Base64.decode(s))
(_.isSuccess)

x match {
  case base64Url(y) => println("Decoded URL =" + y)
  case base64(y)    => println("Decoded     =" + y)
  case _            => println("Could not decode " + x)
}

